# The tag <labal> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter

Tags: reactjs, jsx, warnings

When I use  tag on react, it shows a warning. My code and warning message is given billow.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Use the correct spelling for `label`.

Answer (score 0):

Your tag should be `<label>`, otherwise browser cannot identify it.